# QGIS shows the same label twice

Tags: qgis, qgis-2

In QGIS 2.18, I have a shapefile of lines whose attributes are the lengths (in Km) of the lines. When displaying the labels of this attribute they appear repeated, as seen below:

[image]

How do I get the information to appear only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the labeling-dialogue, go to the placement-tab and check if "repeat" is set to 0 (no repetition) - based on QGIS 3.8, but if I remember well it was the same back in version 2.18

Comment: Hello, thanks for your time. I checked what you told me and "repeat" is set to 0; however, the labels keep repeating.

Comment: What have you defined as labeling source? Can you post a screenshot of you label-placement dialogue? It's hard to say what caused the problem without further information.

Comment: I already found the error. Reviewing the fields I just realized that for each line in the image there are actually two lines in opposite directions; At the time of calculating the lengths of the lines, I did not verify that there were no repeated lines and that is the reason why the same label appears twice.
Thank you very much for your time and attention.

Comment: @jvl You could post that as an answer, it might help other people who have the same issue. (Believe me, you're not the first.)